# How to project galaxy data in x y z coordinates?

Tags: galaxy, coordinate, space-geometry

For a data visualization project, I want to extract galaxy data (in x y z coordinates) from galaxy catalogue of within 150 mpc and project each of those galaxies as dots and visualize them in a 2D projection of a spherical volume. Need your help in getting this data set and how to achieve it?

Would be grateful for any help in any way!

Comment: The NED database https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu

Comment: http://www.usno.navy.mil/USNO/astrometry/optical-IR-prod/nomad contains one billion objects, but you probably won't need something that extreme.

Comment: Every catalog of galaxies is going to be missing all those galaxies that lie behind the milkyway. There will be a big slice missing, whatever data you use.

Comment: @barrycarter As I'm sure I've mentioned before (?), Nomad is mostly a stellar catalogue.

Comment: @RobJeffries You are correct.  http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/cgro/db-perl/W3Browse/w3table.pl?MissionHelp=galaxy_catalog may be more helpful.

Comment: thanks for your answers. sorry to sound so dumb but on Nomad website, where do i go from there? What dataset do i download and what software do i use to project in xyz coordinates? I am trying to get something like this pic-- https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March12/Coil/Coil1.html

Answer (score 3):

You could try the [Hyperleda](http://leda.univ-lyon1.fr) database. You will have to learn to use the database, which possibly means learning a little bit of SQL. For starters you could select all items with redshift $cz < H_0\times 150$ km/s, using redshift as a distance indicator. This should be roughly ok at 150 Mpc (though I don't see any viable alternative).

The returned catalogue should have (at least) RA, Dec, redshift, possibly a size and morphology and, for a small subset of the galaxies, a redshift-independent distance estimate. Given that very nearby galaxies (in the local group or a $d < 50 $Mpc) are not fully part of the "Hubble flow" you might choose to use these in preference to a redshift-distance where available.

X,Y,Z coordinates (based in the equatorial system) can be calculated using [this prescription](http://www.astronexus.com/a-a/positions) or in Galactic coordinates (with respect to the centre and orientation of our Galaxy can then be found using the operations defined in [Johnson & Soderblom (1987)](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1987AJ.....93..864J).

I have no idea how complete this database will be. Certainly there will be an issue with extinction near the Galactic plane.

Comment: For nearby galaxies, do you mean that redshift-independent distance is preferable to redshift?

Comment: @MikeG Yes I do. Edited.